# Applying filter to pandas dataframe as a parameter to function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to pass single(mandatory) parameter to function, how can we make this working.
Need to pass only 1 argument in func2 so that i can call using 1 argument in df_test

```
Source Data
data_list = [
  {"col1": "", "col2": "xx", "col3": "00001-1", "col4": "", "col5": "", "col6": "xx"},
  {"col1": "1", "col2": " aaa ", "col3": "00001-3", "col4": "0", "col5": "", "col6": "xx - abc"},
  {"col1": "1", "col2": "xx zzz", "col3": "00001-4", "col4": "0", "col5": "", "col6": "xx yyy"}
]

#Converting to dataframe:
def convert_to_df(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip())
    df = df.replace('', np.nan)   
    return df   
  
df_test = convert_to_df(data)
print(df_test)

#function for filtering to call in df_test  
def func2(col1):    
    df2 = convert_to_df("col1 == @col1")
    return df2  
    
Need to pass only 1 argument in func2, without passing data_list. As this data_list - source data is created by other process.
df_test = func2(1)
```

Expected output:

```
print(df_test)
  col1    col2     col3 col4  col5      col6
0    1     aaa  00001-3    0   NaN  xx - abc
1    1  xx zzz  00001-4    0   NaN    xx yyy
```

Comment: Your explanation of what you are trying to do is not very clear.  Could you explain more fully what you mean by"Need to pass only 1 argument in func2 so that i can call using 1 argument in df_test"?  It would be helpful if you could edit your question to add an expected output for a complete example, given inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly you could do something along the lines of:

```
def convert_to_df(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip())
    df = df.replace('', np.nan)   
    return df   

def funct2(fltr):
    df = convert_to_df(data_list)
    return df[eval(fltr)]
```

Then executing:

```
funct2("df['col1'] == '1'")
```

Yields:

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
1   1   aaa 00001-3 0   NaN xx - abc
2   1   xx zzz  00001-4 0   NaN xx yyy
```